# Can't access my Postgresql server from workstations

Tags: postgresql

I've installed Postgresql 9.4 on a windows server 2008. I am writing an application that will access this server from our Windows 7 machines. I also installed PGAdminIII on one workstation where I am developing.

I am not able to connect from the workstations. I get a "Server doesn't listen" message. I've looked online for some solutions but none seemed to help me.

On the Server where the service is running. I've tried and change the values through paAdminIII for the files pg_hba.conf and

It looks like pg_hba.conf was setup to listen to the loopback and then a range of ip addresses on the same computer. When I change the "host" key value of the ip_address range from 127.0.0.1/32 to 192.168.2.1/128 (and keep the other values the same -> all, all, md5) the service starts and then stop immediately.

If I leave it with 127.0.0.1/32 then it starts fine but I can not connect from the workstation.

I left the listen_addresses on the postgresql.conf file as the default "*" which is trying to listen to all addresses.

I am trying to develop a client/server app before moving it to the cloud and this is step 0.

I did install on my Windows 7 machine an "add_on" the VisualStudio to help me get a connect string down the line but I am only using the PostgreSql "tools" at this time.

I did some search to see if this question was asked before in this client/server scenario and did not find one. If it has already been answered I'd appreciate some pointers directing me to the correct way to configure server access, if not, then an answer on how to do it would be great.

I can ping the server with no problems from the workstation(s).

Comment: pg_hba.conf is definitely the file you need to edit. Can you show us the edit you did that caused the server to stop? And if possible,the error the server logged in that case? But typically you will *add* "host" lines, not modify those provided for localhost... Like this line, `host all all    192.168.1.0/24 md5` - just an example that works in a specific case, don't just slap that line in your pg_hba.conf :)

Answer (score 0):

The IP address/CIDR mask specification of `192.168.2.1/128` is wrong. The last value indicates the *number of bits to be masked*, not an IP address range. If you want (most of) the range `192.168.2.1 - 192.168.2.128`, the entry in `pg_hba.conf` should be `192.168.2.0/25` (meaning: take the three highest bytes `192.128.2` (24 bits), plus the highest order bit `0` of the last byte and let the 7 remaining bits vary (values `0` to `127`).

Note that this includes `192.168.2.0` and excludes `192.168.2.128`, but that is just how bit masking of IP addresses works. You could add `192.168.2.128` with a separate entry in `pg_hba.conf`, but you cannot get `192.168.2.0` out.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. I've stopped the service on the server, changed the pg_hba.conf to have the IP4 range be 192.168.2.0/25

Comment: Thank you Patrick.  I've stopped the service on the server, changed the pg_hba.conf to have the IP4 range be 192.168.2.0/25 and resume the service. On my workstation tried to configure the server access with PgAdminIII and got the same error (Server does not listen) - on the config page I have the server name as "PostgreSQL 9.4",  my Host as the UNC of the host "\\ServerName.."  Port 5432 and db user id...

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the full IP connection section from `pg_hba.conf` (those lines starting with `host`). Also paste in the relevant parts of `ipconfig /all` (on the server).

Comment: ipv4 all all 192.168.2.0/25 md5, ipv6 all all ::1/128 md5 (not used) --- ipconfig preferred ipv4 192.168.2.10, gateway 192.168.2.1 subnet 255.255.255.0 gateway is also the intranet DNS server. My workstation ip is 192.168.2.122

Comment: my default gateway (on the workstation) is 192.168.2.1 with the same subnet mask as in the previous comment

Comment: Ok, it should be `host all all 192.168.2.0/25 md5`, not `ipv4 etc`.

Comment: Sorry Patrick, there is no ipv4 on the pg_hba.conf is just that the line pertains to ipv4 and the other line that has :: pertains to ipv6. It is not working and I am now looking at the Firewall.  We have Symantec End Point Protection and it takes over the Firewall, I'll try and open the port and see the results. Thanks for your help anyways.